# v-checkbox in v-for on check save selected to data vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i create v-checkbox in v-for, what i want is when it is check save selected to data array, and when uncheck unset from array
here is my code

```
<v-row v-for="basket in baskets" :key="basket.id">
    <v-col>
        <v-card
        >
          <div class="d-flex justify-space-between">
            <p><span class="text-bold ml-2">{{basket.name}} </span>  
              <span class="text-small ml-2">{{basket.description}}</span>
            </p>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="basket.make_order" @change="check_Basket(basket)"
            ></v-checkbox>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-space-between">
            <p> <span class="text-small ml-2">price :</span> {{basket.price}}</p> 
            <p class="mr-2"> <span class="text-small">total :</span> {{basket.qty}} {{basket.unit}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-space-between">
            <p> <span class="text-small ml-2">Total :</span> {{basket.total}}</p> 
            <p class="mr-2"> <span class="text-small">from :</span> {{basket.store_name}}</p>
          </div>      
        </v-card>
    </v-col>      
</v-row>

<v-row>
    <v-btn 
    @click="make_Order"
    class="primary">make order</v-btn>
</v-row>
```

and this is my scrip

```
data () {
      return {
        baskets:[],
        checked:[],
      }
    },
    methods:{
      check_Basket(value){
        this.checked.push(value.id)
        console.log(this.checked)
      },
      make_Order()
        console.log(this.checked)
      }
    }
```

please note that i have correct data in array baskets,

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the `v-model` to `checked` property and `value` to the current `basket.make_order` :

```
 <v-checkbox  :value="basket.make_order" v-model="checked" ></v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly vuetify checkbox already have that functionality, no need to write a methode for that.

just need to pass the value and the array that will contain the values
here is the documentation [checkbox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/#model-as-array)

```
<v-checkbox  :value="basket.make_order" v-model="checked" ></v-checkbox>
```

Comment: does not work, fyi basket.make_order is column from backend, the default is always null, that same as my expectation when open always uncheck

Answer (score 0):

oh i got the answer, you need to model under basket.checked
and in save button u make condition check into baskets array if checked == true then you can post to backend

```
 <v-checkbox
   v-model="basket.checkbox"
 ></v-checkbox>
```

and this is scrip

```
make_Order(){
        this.baskets.forEach((e)=>{
          if(e.checkbox == true){
            this.selected.push(e);
          }
        });

        console.log(this.selected);
      }
```